# Can gif animation be started only after containing slick.js slide is shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slick.js, animated-gif

Using Slick.js.: I would like a gif animation to start only after its containing slide is shown.

I suspect this is very basic, and event names such as afterChange — referring to slides — shown in the official slick.js page, make me assume they're meant to achieve goals like mine? Just wondering... If so, how do I use the events? If not, can you suggest a way to do it? Oh... my JS is not very good, please take that into account. Thanks all!

```
<li id="xprmntl_one">
<div class="grid">
<img src="../PROJIMGS/XPRMNTL/animation/grid.png">
</div>
<div class="design">
<img src="../PROJIMGS/XPRMNTL/animation/design.png">
<img src="../PROJIMGS/XPRMNTL/animation/top_elements.png">
</div>
<div class="browser_animation">
<img src="../PROJIMGS/XPRMNTL/animation/layout_animation.gif">
<img src="../PROJIMGS/XPRMNTL/animation/browser_&_alpha.png">
</div>
</li>


$('#xprmntl_one').slick({
dots: false,
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
fade: true,
cssEase: 'linear',
autoplay: false,
prevArrow: '<span style="display:block" class="navItemCointainer left"><span class="slick-prev navItem"><</span></span>',
nextArrow: '<span style="display:block" class="navItemCointainer right"><span class="slick-next navItem">></span></span>',    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to use a custom `data-` attribute on the slides that contain GIF images. Here's an example using the `beforeChange` event to check if the next slide's image is a GIF:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#carousel").slick().on("beforeChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        // Use the "nextSlide" variable to find the <img> in the next slide
        var nextSlideImg = $("#carousel [data-slick-index='" + nextSlide + "'] img");

        // Check if it has a custom "data-gif" attribute
        if (nextSlideImg.attr("data-gif")) {
            var gifUrl = nextSlideImg.attr("data-gif");

            // Set the placeholder image to the .gif so it plays from the beginning
            nextSlideImg.attr("src", gifUrl);
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carousel">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=Img 1" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=Placeholder" data-gif="https://i.imgur.com/T3bOme7.gif" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300?text=Img 2" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try this out.